# How to accept data as input from console using docker-compose for a python program?

Tags: docker-compose

> This is my .py file:

```
import re

input_string=input()
regex = '>(.+?)<'
print(re.findall(regex,input_string))
```

> This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
mpython:
build: ./
command: test.py
```

> this is dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR D:\

COPY ./test2.py D:\question_3
RUN pip install regex
```

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose exec mpython {input}